# Proteins and their solubility

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

I have 2 statements , and i am not sure, whether they are true or false.

1. Proteins like albumin and haemoglobin are insoluble in water

(in my view , almost all proteins are soluble- so this is a wrong  statement)

1. Proteins which are soluble in water have complex 3D structure and they are globular molecules. - (in my view I think this is also wrong)

Please explain these statements.

Comment: I think 2nd is correct, but have no idea  about 1st. Take a look at [image](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Factu.epfl.ch%2Fimage%2F14719%2F324x182.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fisic.epfl.ch%2Fpage-100699-en.html&h=181&w=324&tbnid=GkcA9caRbqWzhM%3A&zoom=1&docid=rFLeJO4Mo1I-KM&ei=5PfqU6GJIdiE8gWd2oIg&tbm=isch&client=ubuntu-browser&ved=0CEsQMyglMCU&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=892&page=3&start=37&ndsp=22) of proteins soluble in water

Comment: If 2nd is correct, it sense only globular proteins are soluble? I am not sure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All proteins have complex structures. There are three broad classes: globular, membrane and scleroproteins. Globular proteins are generally water soluble while membrane and scleroproteins are not.

Albumins and haemoglobin are globular and water soluble.